# General Retry Strategy

Tags: c#, design-patterns, error-handling

Let’s say we copy some file using retry strategy (it might be blocked, etc.):

```
class Processor
{
    public void CopyData() =>
        CopyData(Try.Slow);

    public void CopyData(Try loop) =>
        loop.Execute(() => 
            File.Copy(@"c\a.txt", @"c:\b.txt"));
}
```

What do you think about names chosen for the following library code identifiers? Would you name them differently?

```
public abstract class Try
{
    public static Try Repeat(params int[] delays) => new Repeat(delays);
    public static readonly Try Never = Repeat();
    public static readonly Try Once = Repeat(0);
    public static readonly Try Slow = Repeat(0, 500, 1500, 4500, 12000);
    public static readonly Try Fast = Repeat(0, 50, 150, 450, 1200);
    public abstract void Execute(Action action);
}

class Repeat : Try
{
    IReadOnlyList<int> Delays { get; }

    public Repeat(params int[] delays)
    {
        Delays = delays;
    }

    public override void Execute(Action action)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< Delays.Count; i++)
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(Delays[i]);
                action();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (i == Delays.Count - 1)
                    throw;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related, the little-known *circuit breaker* pattern. Martin Fowler has a great article about it [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yep, it is in my answer below :)

Comment: My standard caution whenever someone posts about this pattern: *it composes poorly with itself*, so be cautious.

Comment: My standard caution whenever someone uses Thread.Sleep: workers are expensive; don't pay them to sleep.  Schedule the task to be resumed asynchronously, rather than putting the thread to sleep and blocking all progress on this thread.  Your code is a disaster waiting to happen on the UI thread.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks, I would probably need two methods: `Execute` (event based with optional cancellation) and `ExecuteAsync` version (Task.Delay with optional cancellation). We are still need to be synchronous sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be more useful if  the user could specify an interval and how many times he wants to retry like:

```
public static Try Repeat(int dalay, int count) 
    => new Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(delay, count));
```

or if he could specify a count and the increment function:

```
public static Try Repeat(int count, Func<int, int> increment) 
    => new Repeat(Enumerable.Range(1, count + 1).Select(x => increment(x));
```

where the increment could be:

```
x => x * 20
```

---

I wouldn't provide such members as `Fast` or `Slow` because they are very subjective and what for you currently is *slow* might be in my application still too fast.

`Never` does not make any sense ;-) Why should I want to never try to execute something? I might as well not write the code at all if it shouldn't run :-P

---

One more thoght. How about specifying the retry strategy via a generic argument:

```
class SlowTry : Repeat
{
    public SlowTry() : base(0, 500, 1500, 4500, 12000) { }
}
```

the  `Try` becomes this:

```
public abstract class Try
{
    ... stays the same

    public static void Execute<TStrategy>(Action action) where TStrategy : Try, new()
    {
        new TStrategy().Execute(action);
    }
}
```

use:

```
Try.Execute<SlowTry>(() => File.Copy(@"c\a.txt", @"c:\b.txt"));
```

This way the user can easier specify his strategy.

Comment: 1) Yep, `Repeat` looks like a missing one. 2) `Fast` and `Slow` save a lot of typing, I could probably define them somewhere else in the app - like to `IORetry.Slow`.  3) `Never` is just a [NULL object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern; it allows deciding at run-time - let's say - it indicates how many times a `LogWriter` will try to access the DB for this exactly operation.

Comment: Oops ;-) you're right of course about the null pattern, I do it myself all the time. I don't know what I was thinking while writing this... But the fact is, I was awake just for ten minutes at that time. Forgive me ;-D

Comment: @DmitryNogin see the edit. I've added one more idea.

Comment: Actually we can do it without using generics: `class IOTry { Try Slow = Try.After(0,1000,2000); }’ and then `IOTry.Slow.Execute(() => {})`. It is a way cheaper and simpler to pass an instance instead of type parameter around.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement a cancellation mechanism. In worst case scenario you will have to wait for almost 20 seconds for `CopyData()` to return with no way to interrupt this operation, except for maybe aborting the thread (which is hardly an option). This might not be as important for server-side application, but it is extremely important for clients, who should always have the ability to close the application or cancel pending operation. In general, I think using `Thread.Sleep` is almost always a poor design decision, and it can always be replaced with a wait handle of choice.

**Edit:** here is a simple example of cancellation, which uses tasks:

```
public LoopHandle Execute(Action action)
{
    return Execute(ct => action());
}

public LoopHandle Execute(Action<CancellationToken> action)
{
    //You might want to properly dispose CancellationTokenSource later on. 
    //Or you can let GC call its finalizer later. Same goes for tasks.
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Delays.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Delays[i])) return;
                action(token);
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (i == Delays.Count - 1) throw;
            }
        }
    }, token);
    return new LoopHandle(task, cts);
}

public class LoopHandle
{
    public LoopHandle(Task task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        _task = task;
        _tokenSource = tokenSource;
    }

    //or you can just expose the task itself
    public void Wait()
    {
        //this will throw if Execute threw
        _task.Wait();
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private readonly Task _task;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
}
```

You can still run it synchronously by calling `loop.Execute(...).Wait()`.
I think this approach is more universal, if the goal is to create *general* retry strategy, but you can do the same thing without tasks, if you already have the background thread which executes this long-running method.

Comment: Have you an idea for the cancellation? I'm not very good at this (I mean cancelling a _task_ that waits for something).

Comment: @t3chb0t, I've added example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be:

```
public abstract class Try
{
    public static Try After(params int[] delays) => new Repeat(delays);
    public static readonly Try Never = After();
    public static readonly Try Once = After(0);
    public static readonly Try Slow = After(0, 500, 1500, 4500, 12000);
    public static readonly Try Fast = After(0, 50, 150, 450, 1200);
    public static readonly Try InASecond = After(1000);
    public static readonly Try InAMinute = After(60000);
    public abstract void Execute(Action action);

    public Try FailFast() => FailFast(0);
    public Try FailFast(int timeout) => new Breaker(this, timeout);
}
```

where delays are provided by:

```
class Repeat : Try
{
    IReadOnlyList<int> Delays { get; }

    public Repeat(params int[] delays)
    {
        Delays = delays;
    }

    public override void Execute(Action action)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< Delays.Count; i++)
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(Delays[i]);
                action();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (i == Delays.Count - 1)
                    throw;
            }
    }
}
```

and circuit breaker pattern is implemented as:

```
class Breaker : Try
{
    Try Loop { get; }
    TimeSpan Timeout { get; }
    DateTime Ready { get; set; }

    public Breaker(Try loop, int timeout)
        : this(loop, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
    {
    }

    public Breaker(Try loop, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Loop = loop;
        Timeout = timeout;
        Ready = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public override void Execute(Action action)
    {
        if (Ready > DateTime.Now)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();

        try
        {
            Loop.Execute(action);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (Timeout == TimeSpan.Zero)
                Ready = DateTime.MaxValue;
            else
                Ready = DateTime.Now + Timeout;

            throw;
        }   
    }
}
```