# General Retry Strategy #2

Tags: c#, design-patterns, error-handling, asynchronous

[Previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/general-retry-strategy)

*Now supports async operations and cancellation.*

Let’s say we copy some file using retry strategy (it might be blocked, etc.). App code comes bellow:

```
class Processor
{
    public void CopyData() =>
        CopyData(IOTry.Slow);

    public void CopyData(Try loop) =>
        loop.Execute(() => 
            File.Copy(@"c\a.txt", @"c:\b.txt"));
}
```

Where:

```
public class IOTry
{
    public static readonly Try Slow = Try.Retry(delay: 1000, times: 4, ratio: 3);
    public static readonly Try Fast = Try.Retry(delay: 100, times: 4, ratio: 3);
}
```

Library code is a way longer now - anybody see a way to simplify?

```
public abstract class Try
{
    public static readonly Try Never = new Never();
    public static readonly Try Once = Retry(delay: 0, times: 0, ratio: 0);

    public static Try Retry(int delay, int times, double ratio) =>
        RetryAfter(from i in Enumerable.Range(0, times)
                   select delay * Math.Pow(ratio, i) into d
                   select (int)d);

    public static Try RetryAfter(params int[] delays) => RetryAfter(delays.AsEnumerable());
    public static Try RetryAfter(IEnumerable<int> delays) => new Retry(delays);

    public void Execute(Action action) => Execute(action, CancellationToken.None);
    public abstract void Execute(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    public Task ExecuteAsync(Action action) => ExecuteAsync(action, CancellationToken.None);
    public Task ExecuteAsync(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => 
        ExecuteAsync(() => { action(); return Task.CompletedTask; }, cancellationToken);

    public Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action) => ExecuteAsync(action, CancellationToken.None);
    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    public Try FailFast() => FailFast(0);
    public Try FailFast(int timeout) => new Breaker(this, timeout);
}
```

And NULL Object pattern:

```
class Never : Try
{
    public override void Execute(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And:

```
class Retry : Try
{
    IEnumerable<int> Delays { get; }

    public Retry(IEnumerable<int> delays)
    {
        Delays = delays;            
    }

    public override void Execute(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var delay in Delays)
            try
            {
                action();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(delay);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

        action();
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var delay in Delays)
            try
            {
                await action();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
            }

        await action();
    }
}
```

And Circuit Breaker pattern:

```
class Breaker : Try
{
    Try Loop { get; }
    TimeSpan Timeout { get; }
    DateTime Ready { get; set; }

    public Breaker(Try loop, int timeout)
        : this(loop, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout))
    {
    }

    public Breaker(Try loop, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Loop = loop;
        Timeout = timeout;
        Ready = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public override void Execute(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (Ready > DateTime.Now)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();

        try
        {
            Loop.Execute(action, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (Timeout == TimeSpan.Zero)
                Ready = DateTime.MaxValue;
            else
                Ready = DateTime.Now + Timeout;

            throw;
        }
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (Ready > DateTime.Now)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();

        try
        {
            await Loop.ExecuteAsync(action, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (Timeout == TimeSpan.Zero)
                Ready = DateTime.MaxValue;
            else
                Ready = DateTime.Now + Timeout;

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `{}`-less loops are a real challange for me :-P

Comment: One could say that Python is an absolute winner in data science because of its readability – they do need it to deliver – it is not redundantly obfuscated with useless brackets :-P

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. I find python extremely hard to read for its lack of brackets. It's so easy to make a mistake by a simple indentation error. In VS you press a key combination and your code is _perfectly_ formatted and you easily see the structure. In python you have to do it yourself and if you're lucky the code even works.

Comment: You are definitely not alone on that side of the force :) The same time – just google “Python vs C#”; you will see almost everybody stating that `Python is better in readability, C# has more consistent syntax` [link](https://www.quora.com/Can-C-do-everything-that-Python-can/answer/Alex-Yakunin?srid=h9L1&share=1), etc.

Comment: How are clients of the API supposed to know that the constructor `Breaker(Try loop, int timeout)` expects milliseconds? I would name the parameter `timeoutInMs` (as clumsy as it sounds) or remove the constructor altogether.

Comment: One more question, why does the _normal_ `Execute` requires a `CancellationToken`? I thought only `async` would require this. Could you explain what this is for?

Comment: Another thing I don't quite understand is that you call the `action` one more time outside the loop. Why? This isn't inside a `try/catch` anymore, is this intended?

Comment: @t3chb0t 1) Synchronous `Execute` could be executed by the background thread, so there is still a possibility to have someone who will be will to cancel it... 2) The very last attempt scheduled happens outside of try/catch to make the possible exception be visible for the client code.

Comment: Ok, I understand the cancellation token now, with the additional `action` I need to argue - I think the solution suggested in my review would be better - also if I specify 4 different times/intervals the it would execute the action one more time - but maybe I don't want it? I find the loop should `Take(Delays.Count - 1)` in this case.

Comment: “What is in a name?” :) This is a `Retry`, not `Try` strategy, so it takes retry `delays`, first `try` goes immediately. So, for three retry delay – we have 4 execution attempts. At least I saw it that way at 3 am that night :)

Comment: haha ;-) to me it's _re**try**_ so it is a try after all - I'll use it as a `try/catch` replacement anyway - I lately misued the `Aggregate` so I'm gonna misuse this one too ;-P

Comment: The `ratio`parameter of your `Retry` factory method should **never** be smaller or equal to `0.0`. I'd even cap it at `1` with `Math.Max(1, ratio)`. Also it is not a ratio. It's more like a part of a coeefficient to control the growth of the delay so I'd rather name it `growthFactor`, `growthPower`, or just `growth` (the first two are still a lie, but easier to understand).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yep, thank you. I just borrowed `ratio` term from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going to borrow your code and implement it in my application ;-) but there is one thing that I'm missing here. I needed to know which exceptions were thrown.

That's why I want to suggest you to extend the framework so that after the retries are finished you can log what happened.

I could imagine the new API like this:

```
class Processor
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = ...;

    public void CopyData() =>
        CopyData(IOTry.Slow);

    public void CopyData(Try loop) =>
        loop.Execute(() => 
            File.Copy(@"c\a.txt", @"c:\b.txt"),
            ex => _logger.Log(ex)
        );
}
```

where the second lambda passes either each exception that occured or a collection of exceptions or an `AggregateException` - perhaps all three APIs make sense in different situations.

The API could either pass each exception that occured right away or collect them and pass them to *me* when the retry is finished. I'm not sure what could work best.

Comment: I would probably have `void ILog.LogIfError(Action)` and `T ILog.LogIfError<T>(Func<T>)` and put it inside of the existing lambda.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Mhmm, then it wouldn't make sense, to have a `try/catch` inside the action and another one in the retry, I thougt the retry could be used so that I don't have to `try/catch` everything....

Comment: I mean `try.Execute(() => log.IfError(() => File.Copy("a","b")));` No more try catch actually to be written again and again. It could also be `log.IfError(() => try.Execute(() => log.IfError(() => File.Copy("a","b"))));`  :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin oh no, a lambda-ception - undebuggable? However this would have one drawback, it would log only the last failure, but what if it works, then I wouldn't know about the first 30 attempts, would I want to ignore it?... with each question this becomes more and more interesting ;-]

Comment: t3chb0t It actually logs everything :) It is inside of retry pattern, not outside :)

Comment: We could have a special decorator though, let me try to invent something :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin ok, invent the decorator ;-) and in the meanwhile I spend some time thinking about what to do when you for example want to retry on file-locked-exception (if there is such) and immediately stop on file-not-found-exception? we need to invent a new conditional-retry pattern...

Comment: What do you think about this for [logging](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140694/ambient-context)?

Comment: We could also throw a special `CriticalException` which breaks throw the repeating mechanism of retry strategy.