# Ambient Context

Tags: c#, design-patterns, logging

What do you think about this way to make logging available across the application without passing `log` object around? Let’s say we have something which allows us to write things this way:

> ```
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         using (new Log("c:\\a.txt"))
>             AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync());
>     }
>
>     static async Task MainAsync()
>     {
>         Log.Write("a1"); // Writes to a.txt
>         await Task.Delay(1000);
>         Log.Write("a2"); // Writes to a.txt
>
>         using (new Log("c:\\b.txt"))
>             await F();
>
>         Log.Write("a3"); // Writes to a.txt
>     }
>
>     static async Task F()
>     {
>         Log.Write("b1"); // Writes to b.txt
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is the `Log` library code:

```
class Log : Ambient<Log>
{
    public static void Write(string line) =>
        Current?.WriteCore(line);

    public Log(string fileName)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    void WriteCore(string line) => File.AppendAllText(FileName, line);
    string FileName { get; }
}
```

Where `Ambient<T>` is defined as:

```
class Ambient<T> : IDisposable where T : Ambient<T>
{
    static readonly string Id = typeof(T).FullName;
    protected static T Current
    {
        get { return (T)CallContext.LogicalGetData(Id); }
        set { CallContext.LogicalSetData(Id, value); }
    }

    protected Ambient()
    {
        Previous = Current;
        Current = (T)this;
    }

    public void Dispose() => Current = Previous;
    T Previous { get; }
}
```

Theoretically, per-request instance of `Log` could come from IoC with all the dependencies injected while taking into account ASP.NET applications.

Comment: I see the `CallContext` for the first time and I wonder why such a useful concept is put inside the `Remoting` namespace and not directly under `System` :-| one could think it's only for remoting...

Comment: Historically it used for cross domain/process/machine communications… It is turned out to be useful for asynchronous code also these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code you provided, you are just setting up where the logger is writing to, within a certain context. The reason you may consider passing around a logger object is when you need to have more complicated configuration for setting up a logger object.

It really depends on what you want. On one hand, having a static logger *is nice*. You don't have to worry about having to include a logger param everywhere in your code. Having to refactor your code when you have a bunch of static method calls is a **huge cost** if you decided to change later, to make configuration more flexible.